# Certain image in collection to be bigger than the others

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm relatively new to coding and had been trying out for the past 3 months.

I am working on shopify, and the problem is I need the fourth image in every collection page to be bigger than the rest.

Current theme: minimal
current code in collection:

```
<div class="row products">

{% for product in collection.products limit: settings.pagination_limit %}     
    {% include 'product-loop' with collection.handle %}
{% endfor %}

<div>
```

I've research and it might be something to do with `{% if forloop.index == 4 %}` but I still can't seem to work it out, thus I need any of your professional help with this.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
   {% if forloop.index == 4 %}
     {{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large' | img_tag }}
   {% else %}
     {{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'small' | img_tag }}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [Minimal Shopify theme](http://themes.shopify.com/themes/minimal/styles/fashion), I would suggest doing something like this in **collection.liquid**:

```
<div class="row products">
  {% for product in collection.products limit: settings.pagination_limit %}
    {% if forloop.index == 4 %}
      {% assign image_size = 'large' %} 
    {% else %}
      {% assign image_size = 'small' %} 
    {% endif %}

    {% include 'product-loop' with collection.handle with image_size %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And then change this line in **product-loop.liquid**:

```
<img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.title | escape  }}" />
```

to this:

```
<img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: image_size }}" alt="{{ product.title | escape  }}" />
```

The image for the 4th product in a collection will be large, and all other product images small. If however you want *every* 4th product image to be large, you would put this in **collection.liquid** instead:

```
<div class="row products">
  {% for product in collection.products limit: settings.pagination_limit %}
    {% capture image_size %}{% cycle 'small', 'small', 'small', 'large' %}{% endcapture %}
    {% include 'product-loop' with collection.handle with image_size %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```